# Facebook photo upload error

Tags: php, facebook, stream, photo

Hi Im trying to write a facebook application that will post a photo to a users page.  Ive pretty much word for word followed this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498).

but whenever I try and upload a photo I get this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource."
   }
}
```

I beleive the problem is coming from this code as I'm sending the AppID, AppSecret and post_login_url (which are all correctly populated) however $response is completely blank:

```
   $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
         . "access_token?"
         . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
         . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
         . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
         . "&code=" . $code;
         $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
         $params = null;
         parse_str($response, $params);
         $access_token = $params['access_token'];
```

Any help would be appreciated, as always im on a tight deadline

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: `$response is completely blank` Did you mean you have trouble with `file_get_contents()` function? Did you try to using cURL or fopen() ?

Answer (score 0):

The Application Access token is used to make API calls on behalf of an app, your underlying issue is likely that the API call you're trying to make has to be made on behalf of a User and needs a user access token produced when a user authorises your app.
The code you have above should be fine for getting an App Access token